# The use of "of" at the start of a sentence

Tags: syntactic-analysis, prepositions

> **Of** the tropical storms that occur each year in the North Atlantic,
>   only about five, on the average, are powerful enough to be called
>   hurricanes.

Why does that **"of"** appear at the beginning of the sentence?

Comment: It's serving the same function as "among". As in *Among [all] the tropical storms which.... only about five ...*. To see why "of" is used, consider rephrasing the sentence and moving the specific clause first: *Only about five **of** the tropical storms that occur each year...*. The meaning is the same, the author only moved some clauses around (because he wanted to start with the topic first, tropical storms, before he moved onto the specific details of the powerful ones).

Comment: No problem. You might also enjoy checking out our sister site, dedicated to people like you who are trying to learn English as a foreign language: [ELL.se]. They have some amazing experts over there. They're also just a fun, lively community.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sentences start with Of](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/211441/sentences-start-with-of)

Comment: You missed an opportunity.  You should have titled your question "Of the use of 'of' at the start of a sentence".